# How to debug multiple node projects in vscode debugger?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have two separate node projects in two separate workspaces. I am trying to debug the projects with vscode debugger but I can only debug one project at a time. If I try to launch the debugger for the second project after starting the debugger for the first one, vscode debuggers restarts the first project again.

I have gone through various tutorials and vscode documentation for debugging and vscode debugging for nodejs but to no avail. Following are the launch configurations for both projects.

Project 1(fort):

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch fort",
            "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "start"
            ],
            "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
            "port": 9229
        }
    ]
}
```

Value for `scripts` attribute in `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node --inspect app.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  }
```

Project 2(User Management):

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch User Management",
            "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "start"
            ],
            "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
            "port": 9229
        }
    ]
}
```

Value for `scripts` attribute in `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node --inspect server.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  }
```

As per my understanding after reading the vscode docs, if I have separate `launch.json` present in the `.vscode` folder of the workspaces that particular configuration will be used to launch the debugger.

Perhaps I am missing something in the docs but I have invested enough time and have been unable to figure out a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use two separate ports for the debuggers to attach, e.g:

Project 1:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch fort",
            "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "start"
            ],
            "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
            "port": 9228
        }
    ]
}
```

Or if you want to attach to the process:

```
{
        "type": "node",
        "request": "attach",
        "name": "Attach",
        "port": 9228
}
```

Start node inspect on port 9228:

```
node --inspect=9228 index.js
```

You can keep the defaults for the second project.